# Object persistance on jboss7.1

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss7.x

I would like to make the persistence of objects on a j2EE project with EJB and JSF framework . When compiling on jboss7.1, I encounter this error.Could someone help me.
Thanks, Manuel

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /TestTce.xhtml @16,55 value="#{testBean.codeTce.libType}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'testBean' resolved to null
com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030)
javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960)
javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
```

Comment: Could you post the code of your TestBean class?

Answer (score 0):

```
package ctrl;
```

public class TestBean {

```
TestDao testDaoLocal;

private CodeTce codeTce = new CodeTce();

public void CreateTce() {

}


public void createEmployee() {
    testDaoLocal.ajouter(codeTce);

}
public CodeTce getCodeTce() {
    return codeTce;
}


public void setCodeTce(CodeTce codeTce) {
    this.codeTce = codeTce;
}
```

Comment: I already added this code:                             @ManagedBean(name = "testBean")
@SessionScoped                                                    above the class declaration